# DFT calculations returning different results

Tags: dft, dsp-core

My coworker ran a DFT query using a software in C downloaded to his PC. His results was the following chart:
[image]

I am using a JS tool from [corbanbrook/dsp.js](https://github.com/corbanbrook/dsp.js/)

My results were very different.
[image]

any ideas why, or where to look?

Comment: You could start by not running random software from the internet and go with a known-good library such as FFTW.

Comment: I appreciate that, I did a lot of searching and found most people commenting positively on dsp.js so thats why I selected that for my software.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you use the same scaling and X and Y axis so you compare apples to apples. The upper graph is in power the lower seems to be amplitude
2. Start with a known signal with a known answer. A sine wave or square wave for example and compare the outcome with the expected result.

Comment: Good point.
Yes, we are both testing with same hz, same data.
Point #2 I'll talk to him about so we can compare some results.